# Custom customer attribute not saving to database (from frontend registration form)

Tags: magento

I have added 2 custom attributes to the registration form to collect input from the customer in the frontend.

My problem is that data from the frontend registration form is not being stored in the database.

Any data I enter for these fields in the admin area is being stored, but I need to collect the information from the customers. Here's my code:

**app/code/local/Symphony/Khaos/sql/khaos_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.12-0.1.13.php** (yes, I've tried to get this right a few times ;))

```
<?php 

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'source', array(
    'input' => 'text',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label' => 'Where did you hear about us?',
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'position' => 1,
    'sort_order' => 80,        
));

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'practitioner_referrer', array(
    'input' => 'text',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label' => 'Referring practitioner',
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'position' => 1,
    'sort_order' => 80,        
));


$installer->endSetup();

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'source');
$forms= array('customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create', 'adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register');
$customer->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);
$customer->save(); 

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'practitioner_referrer');
$forms= array('customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create', 'adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register');
$customer->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);
$customer->save();
```

**app/code/local/Symphony/Khaos/Model/Entity/Setup.php**

```
    <?php 
class Symphony_Khaos_Model_Entity_Setup extends Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup
{
    public function getDefaultEntities(){

        return array(

                'source'=>array(
                        'type'=> 'static',
                        'label'=> 'source',
                        'visiable' => true,
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 80,
                ),

                'practitioner_referrer'=>array(
                        'type'=> 'static',
                        'label'=> 'practitioner_referrer',
                        'visiable' => true,
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 80,
                )

        );
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Symphony/Khaos/etc/config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * @category   Symphony
 * @package    Symphony_Khaos
 * @author     ModuleCreator
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
 -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Symphony_Khaos>
            <version>0.1.13</version>
        </Symphony_Khaos>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <khaos>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Symphony_Khaos</module>
                    <frontName>khaos</frontName>
                </args>
            </khaos>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <khaos>
                    <file>khaos.xml</file>
                </khaos>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <khaos>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Symphony_Khaos</module>
                    <frontName>khaos</frontName>
                </args>
            </khaos>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <khaos module="khaos">
                <title>Khaos</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="khaos">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>khaos/adminhtml_khaos</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </khaos>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Symphony_Khaos>
                            <title>Khaos Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </Symphony_Khaos>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <khaos>
                    <file>khaos.xml</file>
                </khaos>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
    <global>
        <models>
            <khaos>
                <class>Symphony_Khaos_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>khaos_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </khaos>
            <khaos_mysql4>
                <class>Symphony_Khaos_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <khaos>
                        <table>khaos</table>
                    </khaos>
                </entities>
            </khaos_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <khaos_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Symphony_Khaos</module>
                    <class>Symphony_Khaos_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </khaos_setup>
            <khaos_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </khaos_write>
            <khaos_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </khaos_read>          
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <khaos>
                <class>Symphony_Khaos_Block</class>
            </khaos>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <khaos>
                <class>Symphony_Khaos_Helper</class>
            </khaos>
        </helpers>   
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                <source><create>1</create><update>1</update></source>
                <practitioner_referrer><create>1</create><update>1</update></practitioner_referrer>
            </customer_account>
        </fieldsets>   
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/design/frontend/metabolics/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
/** @var Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing $this */
?>
<form id="co-billing-form" action="">
<fieldset>
    <ul class="form-list">
    <?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?>
        <li class="wide">
            <label for="billing-address-select"><?php echo $this->__('Select a billing address from your address book or enter a new address.') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li id="billing-new-address-form"<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?> style="display:none;"<?php endif; ?>>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="billing[address_id]" value="<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getId() ?>" id="billing:address_id" />
            <ul>
                <li class="fields"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getAddress()->getFirstname() ? $this->getAddress() : $this->getQuote()->getCustomer())->setForceUseCustomerRequiredAttributes(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn())->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')->toHtml() ?></li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:company"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="billing:company" name="billing[company]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <?php if(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()): ?>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="billing[email]" id="billing:email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
                <li class="wide">
                    <label for="billing:street1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street1" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getStreet(1)) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                <li class="wide">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address %s', $_i) ?>" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street<?php echo $_i ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getStreet($_i)) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
        <?php endfor; ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('customer/address')->isVatAttributeVisible()) : ?>
                <li class="wide">
                    <label for="billing:vat_id"><?php echo $this->__('VAT Number') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="billing:vat_id" name="billing[vat_id]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getVatId()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('VAT Number') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('vat_id') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" name="billing[city]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="billing:city" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                $('billing:region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getRegionId() ?>");
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                            <input type="text" id="billing:region" name="billing[region]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:postcode" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" name="billing[postcode]" id="billing:postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="billing[telephone]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" id="billing:telephone" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:fax"><?php echo $this->__('Fax') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="billing[fax]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getFax()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Fax') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('fax') ?>" id="billing:fax" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php if(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()): ?>

        <?php $_dob = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob') ?>
        <?php $_gender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_gender') ?>
            <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled() || $_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li class="fields">
                <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
                    <div class="field">
                        <?php echo $_dob->setDate($this->getQuote()->getCustomerDob())->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')->toHtml() ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
                    <div class="field">
                        <?php echo $_gender->setGender($this->getQuote()->getCustomerGender())->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')->toHtml() ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif ?>
                </li>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if ($this->isTaxvatEnabled()):?>
                <li><?php echo $this->getTaxvatHtml() ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="fieldset">
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="source" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Where did you hear about us?') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="source" id="source" title="<?php echo $this->__('source') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="practitioner_referrer"><?php echo $this->__('Were you referrered by a practitioner, if so, who?') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="practitioner_referrer" id="practitioner_referrer" title="<?php echo $this->__('practitioner_referrer') ?>" class="input-text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

                <li class="fields" id="register-customer-password">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:customer_password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="billing[customer_password]" id="billing:customer_password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:confirm_password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="billing[confirm_password]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>" id="billing:confirm_password" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn() && $this->customerHasAddresses()):?>
                    <li class="control">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="billing[save_in_address_book]" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Save in address book') ?>" id="billing:save_in_address_book" onchange="if(window.shipping) shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);"<?php if ($this->getAddress()->getSaveInAddressBook()):?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?> class="checkbox" /><label for="billing:save_in_address_book"><?php echo $this->__('Save in address book') ?></label>
                    </li>
                <?php else:?>
                    <li class="no-display"><input type="hidden" name="billing[save_in_address_book]" value="1" /></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
            </ul>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me.tooltip'); ?>
        </fieldset>
     </li>
    <?php if ($this->canShip()): ?>
        <li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_yes" value="1"<?php if ($this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo  $this->__('Ship to this address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = true;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_yes"><?php echo  $this->__('Ship to this address') ?></label></li>
        <li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0"<?php if (!$this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_no"><?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?></label>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php if (!$this->canShip()): ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" value="1" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="buttons-set" id="billing-buttons-container">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?>" class="button" onclick="billing.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
        <span class="please-wait" id="billing-please-wait" style="display:none;">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>
        </span>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var billing = new Billing('co-billing-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/getAddress') ?>address/', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveBilling') ?>');
    var billingForm = new VarienForm('co-billing-form');

    //billingForm.setElementsRelation('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('directory/json/childRegion') ?>', '<?php echo $this->__('Select State/Province...') ?>');
    $('billing-address-select') && billing.newAddress(!$('billing-address-select').value);

    var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'billing:postcode');
    if ($('onepage-guest-register-button')) {
        Event.observe($('onepage-guest-register-button'), 'click', function(event) {
            var billingRememberMe = $('co-billing-form').select('#remember-me-box');
            if (billingRememberMe.length > 0) {
                if ($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) {
                    billingRememberMe[0].hide();
                } else if ($('login:register') && ($('login:register').checked || $('login:register').type == 'hidden')) {
                    billingRememberMe[0].show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

James

Comment: I dont think the <input name=".." is correct, try changing it to <input name="billing[practitioner_referrer]" (or look at the name attribute in the admin view source to see the name)

Comment: Thanks R.S, I tried that but it didn't work. I tried account[practitioner_referrer] as that's what the admin name was, and also billing[practitioner_referrer] when that didn't work.

Comment: Take look at using  `<fieldsets>`  @ http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/know-more-about-your-customers-adding-custom-signup-attributes

Comment: Thanks R.S, I'm using <fieldsets> in my config.xml: <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                <source><create>1</create><update>1</update></source>
                <practitioner_referrer><create>1</create><update>1</update></practitioner_referrer>
            </customer_account>
        </fieldsets>   
    </global>
</config>

Comment: I'm using 1.7.2, Andreys answer worked for me. Thanks for you help, Oğuz and R.S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution is nice, it is close to a working one, however it lacks some final touches.

Note, that it is possible for a Customer to register in two ways - via "Register" link  or during the Checkout. You've provided template code for the Checkout process only, so I'll talk about it only. Implementation for the "Register" link is much more straightforward and seems to be nicely described in the article that has been already provided above: http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/know-more-about-your-customers-adding-custom-signup-attributes

Ok, regarding the Checkout. The issues with the current solution are:

1. Wrong name for the input. It should be `billing[<attribute_name>]`.
2. Data needs to be stored somewhere during the checkout process (new columns in 
   Quote table are needed) and saved to customer profile upon order placing 
   (fieldset rules are needed)

Let's deal with the issues.

The fix for the **template file** is simple - just rename the inputs, they should be:

```
...

<input type="text" name="billing[source]" id="source" title="<?php echo 
$this->__('source') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />

...

<input type="text" name="billing[practitioner_referrer]" id="practitioner_referrer"
title="<?php echo $this->__('practitioner_referrer') ?>" class="input-text" />

...
```

This will make Magento find the entered data at a place, where it is expected to be.

The right sql file (i.e. **mysql4-upgrade-0.1.12-0.1.13.php**) should look like:

```
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable('sales/quote'),
    'customer_source',
    array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'length'    => '64K',
        'comment'   => 'Customer Source'
    )
);

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable('sales/quote'),
    'customer_practitioner_referrer',
    array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'length'    => '64K',
        'comment'   => 'Customer Practitioner Referrer'
    )
);

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'source', array(
    'input' => 'text',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label' => 'Where did you hear about us?',
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'position' => 1,
    'sort_order' => 80
));

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'practitioner_referrer',
    array(
        'input' => 'text',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Referring practitioner',
        'visible' => 1,
        'required' => 0,
        'position' => 1,
        'sort_order' => 80
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'source');
$forms= array('customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create', 'adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register');
$customer->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);
$customer->save();

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'practitioner_referrer');
$forms= array('customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create', 'adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register');
$customer->setData('used_in_forms', $forms);
$customer->save();
```

In that file we create not only the Customer attributes, but also the corresponding columns in Quote table, where entered values will be stored during the Checkout process.

The fieldsets should include rules to convert data from customer to quote and vice versa. So that's how **config.xml** should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @category   Symphony
 * @package    Symphony_Khaos
 * @author     ModuleCreator
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
 -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Symphony_Khaos>
            <version>0.1.13</version>
        </Symphony_Khaos>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <khaos>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Symphony_Khaos</module>
                    <frontName>khaos</frontName>
                </args>
            </khaos>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <khaos>
                    <file>khaos.xml</file>
                </khaos>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <khaos>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Symphony_Khaos</module>
                    <frontName>khaos</frontName>
                </args>
            </khaos>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <khaos module="khaos">
                <title>Khaos</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <items module="khaos">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>khaos/adminhtml_khaos</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </khaos>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Symphony_Khaos>
                            <title>Khaos Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </Symphony_Khaos>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <khaos>
                    <file>khaos.xml</file>
                </khaos>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <khaos>
                <class>Symphony_Khaos_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>khaos_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </khaos>
            <khaos_mysql4>
                <class>Symphony_Khaos_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <khaos>
                        <table>khaos</table>
                    </khaos>
                </entities>
            </khaos_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <khaos_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Symphony_Khaos</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </khaos_setup>
            <khaos_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </khaos_write>
            <khaos_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </khaos_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <khaos>
                <class>Symphony_Khaos_Block</class>
            </khaos>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <khaos>
                <class>Symphony_Khaos_Helper</class>
            </khaos>
        </helpers>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                <source><to_quote>customer_source</to_quote></source>
                <practitioner_referrer><to_quote>customer_practitioner_referrer</to_quote></practitioner_referrer>
            </customer_account>
            <checkout_onepage_quote>
                <customer_source><to_customer>source</to_customer></customer_source>
                <customer_practitioner_referrer><to_customer>practitioner_referrer</to_customer></customer_practitioner_referrer>
            </checkout_onepage_quote>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
</config>
```

Note two things:

- `<create>` and `<update>` directives were removed, because they are
  not needed for the Checkout registration. You may add them back, if
  you need them.
- Custom setup model `Symphony_Khaos_Model_Entity_Setup`
  was removed in favor of `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup`. The
  Customer setup model is enough to do all the tasks. The file with
  custom setup model may be deleted at all. You may return the custom
  model, if you need it for other tasks.

Voila - that's all! These fixes will make customer see two additional fields during the Checkout registration. And the data will be saved to his profile, when the order is submitted.

However, the implementation is not the best one, because it is based on the approach, which has some drawbacks. The approach requires storing data in the Quote table, while those data entries have nothing to do with the Quote model. They just utilize it as a transport. Also, adding new attributes in future, will require doing too much work - modifications must be made to sql file, to config and to the template.

A right approach would be to build a more abstract implementation. The solution should store attribute data in EAV or custom tables, and add them to the Customer/Quote models via observed events, if needed. The templates should show a generic list of attributes, possibly with special rendering models for the ones that require special design.

But for just 2 attributes your approach is fine.

Wish you luck with further work with Magento :)

Comment: nice to see you in here Andrey :)

Comment: Glad that it worked for you, seavers. And nice to see you too Oguz :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you had get referenced old article therefore you have misconfiguration of the attribute creates.

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'practitioner_referrer', array(  
   'type' => 'int',  
   'input' => 'select',  
   'label' => 'Referer Name',
   'global' => 1,
   'visible' => 1,
   'required' => 0,
   'user_defined' => 1,
   'default' => '0',
   'visible_on_front' => 1  
));
```

Try this and let me know the result.